# Parametrized JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema

I have an API which uses the following response structure for its listing endpoints. All have the same metadata fields, varying only on the *items* type:

```
{
  "items": [...],
  "_metadata1": {...},
  ...
  "_metadataN": {...}
}
```

In the component tests I'm validating the response of each endpoint with a JSON schema. For the listing endpoints I ended up having multiple validation JSON schema files differing only in the *items* field reference:

```
...
    "items": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "<item-type-specific-json-schema>.json"
      }
    }
...
```

Is it possible to define a generic parametrized listing schema?
**Is there any way to define parametrized JSON schemas?**

Comment: I describe almost exactly this case here, https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1064#issuecomment-761117265